# Python and PyWebkitGtk Detecting Javascript Event in webkit.WebView

Tags: javascript, python, event-handling, webkit, dom-events

I am trying to detect when a link is pressed within a `webkit.WebView` in Python. Is there a simplistic way to detect when Javascript events occur with `PyWebkitGtk`?

Comment: webview.connect("navigation-requested", handler) will get a link press. For javascript I don't know yet.